# TextInput layout show edittext error icon in center in API17

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am using Appcompact Edittext with TextInput layout.
 When i set error on edittext it show error icon in center of edittext instead of end like below image.

[image: I am getting now like this]

When i remove Textinput layout from layout xml then it show icon at proper place.

**EDIT**
My layout xml like below.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_login_parent_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/activity_user_login_username_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:hint="Username" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/activity_user_login_password_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_login_forgot_pwd_tv"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:text="Forgot Password?" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_login_btn"
        style="@style/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change URL"
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_login_change_url_btn"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/change_url"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My code like this:
[code for login](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9b542537948409ffb0846cb22ca3c801)

Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: use normal EditText with TextInputLayout.

Comment: I can't figure out why are you still using `EditText`'s error methods while `TextInputLayout` has its own and cool one!

Comment: @SnehaSarkar not working  i was tried

Comment: @VishalThakkar, please add ur xml

Comment: @Wizard i was tried before but its takes spaces when we set error and when we set null error then its not release space. so  i was not used it. In past i was face this issue so.

Comment: Space for error will be added dynamicly, when you set error message. For animation of this proccess I suggest to set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` at TextInputLayout

Comment: @VishalThakkar, man check out the answer i posted.

Comment: @W4R10CK i know using textinput layout we can show error message. but for that we have to implement textwatcher also so we can set error null when user write in edittext.  I  just want to know why we can not achieve this using seterror on edittext.

Comment: @VishalThakkar, no u dont have to use textwatcher if showing error in textinputlayout u just have to use setError on layout only.

Comment: @W4R10CK yes we set error now user when write on it. it should remove error. its not happen for that we have to use textwatcher code . where in edittext we dont need to remove error and write textwatcher code its automatically managed.

Comment: @VishalThakkar, dude are u serious there is a way setting error on textInputlayout without textwatcher. If u say I can give u demo here.

Comment: @W4R10CK sorry deart then i dont know please give demo or example link.

Comment: @VishalThakkar. consider accepting an answer if helped.

Comment: @W4R10CK yeah sure but now i am busy in other work so i will try it later.

Answer (score 1):

- Change your `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText>..</>` with `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText>...</>`.
- If problem persist, Try to set your `Error` message just for `TextInputLayout` and remove it from `EditText` object.

Setting error on `InputTextLayout`, change this with your values:

```
private boolean usernameValidation(String your_username){
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(your_username)){
        your_username_inputTextLayout.setError("Enter Username!");
        return false;
    }else {
        your_username_inputTextLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: not working. this validation method fire only when click on login button. if we leave blank filed then it show error thats fine but after shown error when i write any text in it it should remove error that not happen. for   that  i have used text changed listener.

Comment: i put in on create also.and call this method but still not worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use EditText with TextInputLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:hintEnabled="false">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_text"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This way you can create error output according [material design guidlines](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors)

You can also write `app:hintEnabled="true"` to get [floating label](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-labels) for text input.

Comment: Can you explain, how you set error message into `TextInputLayout`?